# Signed apk, app killed only the FIRST time it is run and then crashes when restarted

Tags: android

So I'm all ready with the app, excited and giddy...but alas, what i realised is that the debug version works alright...but when i install the signed version of the app, during the initialization and data download if i press the home key, the app is killed by the system (i know this coz when i start the app again it starts over from the splash screen), and then when i restart it, it crashes, barnacles!!!

the exception, not a very helpful one...

**Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

and this occurs around the viewpager initialization, however, first, i need to know why the hell does the system shut down the app IMMEDIATELY after the first install!!! after the crash, if i close the app and run it again it runs as smooth as my bottom...i bet its even smoother than that...

this only happens on the first install, thats it...after the first install, subsequent(and unavoidable) crash...everything is whack...everything works perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a known issue, albeit took forever to be found:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373#c21